# concate dataframes in pandas gives different results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code I am trying.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2], 'c2':[3,4]},
                   index=['r1','r2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[5,6], 'c2':[7,8]},
                   index=['r3','r4'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[5,6], 'c2':[7,8]}, index=['r1', 'r2'])



concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print('{}\n'.format(concat))

concat = pd.concat([df1, df3], axis=1)
print('{}\n'.format(concat))
```

The output is different for both concate operations. I am not sure why.

```
     c1   c2   c1   c2
r1  1.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
r2  2.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
r3  NaN  NaN  5.0  7.0
r4  NaN  NaN  6.0  8.0

    c1  c2  c1  c2
r1   1   3   5   7
r2   2   4   6   8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strange but the thing is that row labels or columns labels should be same for pandas to concat rows or columns below the other one. Otherwise it will create this kind of output with NANs.

Comment: It is expected as pandas align on indexes. so same indexes are concatted while non matching indexes are retained with `nan`s